# SCRIPT5022 error (throw,try,catch) only in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have 2 forms (**Father** and **Son**) in **Father** i have a **Table** with a button call to **Son**, here i load a catalog and then with java script send the information to **Father's Table** in a new row and then close **Son**.
Everithing works great in Chrome, Safari(Windows and Mac), Firefox, Opera, even in Vivaldi but in Internet Exporer (i have only tested in the 11 version) only make the new row in the **Father's Table**, the information is never send and **Son** never close, i print the information and all the data is there, but can't send to **Father**. 
In the console says something like:  **SCRIPT5022 error** you have include a **throw** but isn't inside of a **try** or there is no **catch**, this is my code:

```
 function send(dato1,dato2)
   {              
        var TBODY = window.opener.document.formulario.getElementById("mi_tabla_en_padre").getElementsByTagName ("tbody")[0];
        var NUEVO_RENGLON   = TBODY.insertRow(TBODY.rows.length);    

        var NUEVA_CELDA  = NUEVO_RENGLON.insertCell(0);
        var NUEVA_CELDA2  = NUEVO_RENGLON.insertCell(1);

        var TEXTO_CELDA  = document.createTextNode(dato1);
        var TEXTO_CELDA2  = document.createTextNode(dato2);

        NUEVA_CELDA.appendChild(TEXTO_CELDA);
        NUEVA_CELDA2.appendChild(TEXTO_CELDA2);        

window.close();
    }
```

Comment: ["SCRIPT5022: Exception thrown and not caught."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7h3yz%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) The code snippet doesn't seem to be related to your problem at all. Please show the code around `throw`.

Comment: that is the point, i never use a **throw** in java script, i dont know why tell me is an error in a **throw** when i never use one and this is all the code for the function

Comment: Hmm... What ever it was (a library feature catching errors? Have you verified the source file is your script?), `window.opener.document.formulario.getElementById` isn't correct. `getElementById` is a method of `document` only, no elements or other objects have it.

Comment: sorry im a begginer in the web programing, i dont knew that, i run the code and work fine in all the browsers except in Internet Explorer, let me investigate another way to acces to the **Father's** controls

Comment: The method could be added to elements by a library. Are you using any libraries?

Comment: no, i don't use any library, i only use this code to send the information to the **Father** form

Comment: Umh... `window.opener.document.formulario.getElementById` will throw an error in any browser, unless `gEBI` was added to `.formulario` somehow. You haven't used `throw`, no libraries? Spooky ...

Comment: spooky indeed, and as i was saying before, work great in other browsers except Internet Explorer